# How to convert Euler Angles to Front, Up, Right vectors

Tags: c++, opengl, 3d, glm-math

I need a function that given Yaw, Pitch, and Roll, can produce the Front (or Looking At), Right, and Up vectors in "world coordinates".

In my particular world space, starting from the origin (0,0,0), X is positive to the left, Z is positive going away from the viewer/origin, and Y is positive going up.

For for example, given... (angles in degrees)

- yaw=0, pitch=0, roll=0, 
  the expected output is:

  - front = (0.0,0.0,1.0)
  - right = (-1.0,0.0,0.0)
  - up    = (0.0,1.0,0.0)
- yaw=90, pitch=0, roll=0, 
  the expected output is:

  - front = (1.0,0.0,0.0)
  - right = (0,0,0.0,1.0)
  - up    = (0.0,1.0,0.0)
- yaw=0, pitch=90, roll=0, 
  the expected output is:

  - front = (0.0,1.0,0.0)
  - right = (-1.0,0.0,0.0)
  - up    = (0.0,0.0,-1.0)
- yaw=0, pitch=0, roll=90, 
  the expected output is:

  - front = (0.0,0.0,1.0)
  - right = (0.0,1.0,0.0)
  - up    = (1.0,0.0,0.0)

The language I'm working in is C++, and I will gladly use glm to solve this problem if that makes the most sense. If I can get there through quaternion's I'm fine with that solution as well, since I've found other tutorials that describe how to get a quaternion from euler angles.

Comment: what are the vectors with no rotation?

Comment: I think you're asking, if I give it a yaw=0, pitch=0, roll=0, what are the expected results.

The expected results in this case would be:

front=(0.0,0.0,1.0)
right=(-1.0,0.0,0.0)
up=(0.0,1.0,0.0)

Thanks.

Comment: That is the same as the result for yaw=90

Comment: Sorry Vaugh - I had a typo, I've fixed it above and added the yaw=0 example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a full working example.  It isn't very C++-like.  You would probably want to use a real matrix class, but it should be ok for demonstration purposes.  One thing that isn't clear from your question is the rotation order, but that can easily be changed.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdlib>

typedef float Float;
typedef Float Axis[3];
typedef Axis Axes[3];

static void copy(const Axes &from,Axes &to)
{
  for (size_t i=0; i!=3; ++i) {
    for (size_t j=0; j!=3; ++j) {
      to[i][j] = from[i][j];
    }
  }
}

static void mul(Axes &mat,Axes &b)
{
  Axes result;
  for (size_t i=0; i!=3; ++i) {
    for (size_t j=0; j!=3; ++j) {
      Float sum = 0;
      for (size_t k=0; k!=3; ++k) {
        sum += mat[i][k]*b[k][j];
      }
      result[i][j] = sum;
    }
  }
  copy(result,mat);
}

static void getAxes(Axes &result,Float yaw,Float pitch,Float roll)
{
  Float x = -pitch;
  Float y = yaw;
  Float z = -roll;
  Axes matX = {
    {1,     0,     0 },
    {0, cos(x),sin(x)},
    {0,-sin(x),cos(x)}
  };
  Axes matY = {
    {cos(y),0,-sin(y)},
    {     0,1,      0},
    {sin(y),0, cos(y)}
  };
  Axes matZ = {
    { cos(z),sin(z),0},
    {-sin(z),cos(z),0},
    {      0,     0,1}
  };
  Axes axes = {
    {1,0,0},
    {0,1,0},
    {0,0,1}
  };

  mul(axes,matX);
  mul(axes,matY);
  mul(axes,matZ);

  copy(axes,result);
}


static void showAxis(const char *desc,const Axis &axis,Float sign)
{
  std::cout << "  " << desc << " = (";
  for (size_t i=0; i!=3; ++i) {
    if (i!=0) {
      std::cout << ",";
    }
    std::cout << axis[i]*sign;
  }
  std::cout << ")\n";
}

static void showAxes(const char *desc,Axes &axes)
{
  std::cout << desc << ":\n";
  showAxis("front",axes[2],1);
  showAxis("right",axes[0],-1);
  showAxis("up",axes[1],1);
}

int main(int,char**)
{
  Axes axes;
  std::cout.setf(std::ios::fixed);
  std::cout.precision(1);
  getAxes(axes,0,0,0);
  showAxes("yaw=0, pitch=0, roll=0",axes);
  getAxes(axes,M_PI/2,0,0);
  showAxes("yaw=90, pitch=0, roll=0",axes);
  getAxes(axes,0,M_PI/2,0);
  showAxes("yaw=0, pitch=90, roll=0",axes);
  getAxes(axes,0,0,M_PI/2);
  showAxes("yaw=0, pitch=0, roll=90",axes);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is great Vaughn. I appreciate how the code clearly illustrates how to do the matrix multiplications and how to fill the matrices.

Comment: One small glitch, that I realize was an issue in my specification.

I know from my research that the order of how the yaw, pitch, and roll are applied matters. I'd like to have the yaw applied first, then pitch, then roll.

I found that if I changed the order of the matrix multiplies to:

  mul(axes,matZ);
  mul(axes,matX);
  mul(axes,matY);


I got the behavior I was expecting. 

So, am I understanding correctly that I want to do these multiplies in the reverse order of how I would visualize doing the rotations if I did them by hand using a tinker toy model?

Thanks!

Comment: @BradHefta-Gaub: Depends on how you would do the rotations on your model.  The code is written with fixed axes as opposed to rotating axes, but the only difference is the order of multiplication.